# directory layout for Java 9 modules

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, module-info

I've been trying to write a Java 9 module, but no matter what I do, I get the error "package is empty or does not exist". I've tried searching online for the expected directory layout, and tried every variation on directory layout I can think of, but nothing works.

For example, here is one layout I tried

`bar.foo/module-info.java`

```
module bar.foo {
    exports bar.foo;
}
```

`bar.foo/bar/foo/wtf.java`

```
package bar.foo;

public class wtf {
}
```

However, compilation still gives the same error as usual.

```
> javac bar.foo/module-info.java 
bar.foo/module-info.java:2: error: package is empty or does not exist: bar.foo
    exports bar.foo;
               ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command instead that should work is :

```
javac bar.foo/module-info.java bar.foo/bar/foo/wtf.java
```

The reason being, you're trying to compile a class which requires a package to exist i.e. `bar.foo` in your case. But since you haven't created one, the compiler throws the mentioned error.

It's not about the directory layout but the `.class` evaluated by the compiler. Providing your other class(`bar.foo/bar/foo/wtf.java`) creates the `wtf.class` within that package and hence the compiler would succeedingly compile the `module-info.class` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when trying to add a `module-info.java` to a JAR file for which I didn't have source. I had to add an empty class bar.foo.Bogus and compile with

```
javac bar.foo/module-info.java bar.foo/bar/foo/Bogus.java
```

You can remove the bogus class afterwards.